# fastest way to calculate edges (derivatives) of a big torch tensor

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, convolution, edge-detection

Given a tensor with shape `(b,c,h,w)`, I want to extract edges of the spatial data, that is, calculate `x`, `y` direction derivatives of the `(h,w)` and calculate the magnitude `I=sqrt(|x_amplitude|^2+|y_amplitude|^2)`

---

My current implementation is as followed

```
row_mat = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, -1], [0, 0, 0]])
col_mat = row_mat.T
row_mat = row_mat[None, None, :, :]  # expand dim to convolve with tensor (batch,channel,width,height)
col_mat = col_mat[None, None, :, :]  # expand dim to convolve with tensor (batch,channel,width,height)

def derivative(batch: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    uses convolution to perform x and y derivatives
    :param batch: input tensor batch
    :return: image derivative magnitudes
    """
    x_amplitude = ndimage.convolve(batch, row_mat)
    y_amplitude = ndimage.convolve(batch, col_mat)
    magnitude = np.sqrt(np.abs(x_amplitude) ** 2 + np.abs(y_amplitude) ** 2)
    return torch.tensor(magnitude)
```

I was wondering if there's a faster way, as this approach actually convolves using the definition of a derivative, so there might be downsides to that.

---

**PS**. to test this you can use the tensor `torch.randn(1000,128,28,28)`, as these are the dimension I'm dealing with

Answer (score 1):

For this specific operation you might be able to speed things up a bit by doing it "manually":

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

def derivative(batch: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
  # pad batch
  x = nnf.pad(batch, (1, 1, 1, 1), mode='reflect')
  dx2 = (x[..., 1:-2, :-2] - x[..., 1:-2, 2:])**2
  dy2 = (x[..., :-2, 1:-2] - x[..., 2:, 1:-2])**2
  mag = torch.sqrt(dx2 + dy2)
  return mag
```

Comment: Thank you. would you care to elaborate on the indexing `[..., 1:-2, :-2]`